# CentOS proftpd upgrade from 1.3.1 > 1.3.3

Tags: centos, update, ftp

A simple question just how to update **proftpd** on CentOS 5 (Linux server.domain.com 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Nov 3 16:48:13 EST 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) to most recent version **1.3.3c**?
Would gladly appreciate your help especially if you come more detailed on every step!

Comment: Is the any particular reason you want 1.3.3c, or will a reasonably up-to-date and secure proftpd do you?  rpmforge is currently shipping 1.3.2, and adding rpmforge as a repository and upgrading proftpd then becomes easy.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that Alexy wants 1.3.3c because all previous versions of proftpd have been shown to have a massive security hole that gives root access to any server. See http://www.proftpd.org/

Answer (score 1):

Preform a Proftpd update from Atomic Rocket Turtle.
To apply the update, execute the commands below.

```
# wget -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic |sh
# yum clean all
# yum check-update
# yum upgrade (psa-)proftpd
```

Comment out (psa-) or () if you (dont) use PLESK.

Kind of regards,
Edward

Comment: Hi, Edward!  And thanks a lot for you help but I wasn't able to go through last command. First 3 ones ran successfuly and as I don't use Plesk the last command I used was "yum upgrade psa-proftpd" and I got the following error: "Package(s) psa-proftpd available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
". Trying to install this package I got a lot of transaction check errors.

Comment: like those:  "file /usr/share/man/man1/ftpwho.1.gz from install of psa-proftpd-1.3.3c-2.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package proftpd-1.3.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/proftpd.8.gz from install of psa-proftpd-1.3.3c-2.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package proftpd-1.3.2-1.el5.rf.x86_64"

Comment: First of all, you have to uninstall the old version of Proftpd and then install the latest version from Atomic Turtle. By entering "yum remove proftpd", because you are using a .RF version an the new version will be a .ART version of Proftpd. Then you'll be able to install the new version. Try instead "yum upgrade psa-proftpd" to "yum list updates" and then select proftpd also.

Comment: also could you use "yum list proftpd*" to find your good version.

Comment: When you have removed the old version then you have to install a new version by "yum install proftpd". This should be work, otherwise could i help to take a SSH connection as user. Mail the new account and password to beheer@nachtmarkt.info. (To do this, use "adduser newusername" as root and give me a normal privilage account and password, additonal when i'll finish you could delete by the command "deluser newusername"). Do only this when you trust me.